# Creating an interactive widget in Bokeh using TextInput to alter graph

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to understand how to create an interactive widget with Bokeh. The goal is to have the TextInput box change the x value in the code, and in turn alter the position of the dot on the graph.

If someone could help me out with an example and describe what I should be learning in order to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.models import *
from bokeh.io import *
from bokeh.transform import *
from bokeh.layouts import *
import numpy as np

x = 1
y = 5

def x_funtion(x):
    x_value = x*4
    return x_value

number = x_funtion(x)

def handler(attr, old, new):
    global number
    number = x_funtion(new)
    return number

text_input = TextInput(value=str(x), title="x")
text_input.on_change("value", handler)



p =figure()
p.circle(number,y)


curdoc().title = "Hello, world!"
curdoc().add_root(row(p,text_input))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of handling that, but in the long run it's better to use a `ColumnDataSource`. In general, when you want to update something that's managed by Bokeh, you want to change already existing Bokeh models.

```py
from bokeh.layouts import *
from bokeh.models import *
from bokeh.plotting import *


def x_function(x):
    x_value = x * 4
    return x_value


x_init = 1
ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[x_function(x_init)], y=[5]))


def handler(attr, old, new):
    try:
        new = int(new)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        ds.data['x'] = [x_function(new)]


text_input = TextInput(value=str(x_init), title="x")
text_input.on_change("value", handler)

p = figure()
p.circle('x', 'y', source=ds)

curdoc().title = "Hello, world!"
curdoc().add_root(row(p, text_input))
```